# Abort a build immediately with success status in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any pipeline step available to abort a build on certain cases with success status?

There is an `error` step available to abort a build with failure status. But I don't know about the success status.

Answer (score 2):

As was said in other replies, there isn't a step to abort in this way. As Christopher suggested you can use try-catch around the aborting code and use error(). I think you will need to track the abort status of your build - you could define an abort method globally in the pipeline to set this status and raise an error so it will abort other steps in your stage.

If you used the declarative pipeline you can use a 'when' declaration with an expression in later stages so they don't execute when the abort status is set.

I am interested in this problem myself so I worked out an example of a pipeline that does this here:

```
/**
 * Tracking if the build was aborted
 */
Boolean buildAborted = false

/**
 * Abort the build with a message
 */
def abortBuild = { String abortMessage ->
    buildAborted = true
    error(abortMessage)
}

pipeline {

    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'FailOrAbort', defaultValue: 'ok', description: "Enter 'fail','abort' or 'ok'")
    }

    stages {

        stage('One') {

            steps {

                echo "FailOrAbort = ${params.FailOrAbort}"

                script {

                    try {

                        echo 'Doing stage 1'

                        if(params.FailOrAbort == 'fail') {

                            echo "This build will fail"
                            error("Build has failed")

                        }
                        else if(params.FailOrAbort == 'abort') {

                            echo "This build will abort with SUCCESS status"
                            abortBuild("This build was aborted")

                        }
                        else {

                            echo "This build is a success"

                        }

                        echo "Stage one steps..."

                    }
                    catch(e) {

                        echo "Error in Stage 1: ${e.getMessage()}"

                        if(buildAborted) {
                            echo "It was aborted, ignoring error status"
                        }
                        else {
                            error(e.getMessage())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            post {
                failure {
                    echo "Stage 1 failed"
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Two') {

            when {
                expression {
                    return !buildAborted
                }
            }

            steps {
                echo "Doing stage 2"
            }
        }

        stage('Three') {

            when {
                expression {
                    return !buildAborted
                }
            }

            steps {
                echo "Doing stage 3"
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always  {
            echo "Build completed. currentBuild.result = ${currentBuild.result}"
        }
        failure {
            echo "Build failed"
        }
        success {
            script {
                if(buildAborted) {
                    echo "Build was aborted"
                } else {
                    echo 'Build was a complete success'
                }
            }
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'Build has gone unstable'
        }
    }
}
```

*As a side note there is a property 'currentBuild.result' you can adjust in the pipeline but once set to 'FAILURE' it cannot be cleared back to 'SUCCESS' - the Jenkins model doesn't allow it AFAIK*.

Comment: Kudos for describing the lifecycle of `currentBuild.result` - that has tripped me up more than once.

Answer (score 1):

No, the normal process of a pipeline is to go from start to end.
What you could however do is to test for your success status and just not call the rest of your code, in an if or something like that. Functions could help you achieve that quite easily, e.g. :

```
node() {
  // Part 1
  def isSuccess = part1();

  if(!isSuccess) {
    part2() 
  }
}

// Part 2
def function part2() {
  // Part 2 code
}
```

However, you should be careful with that kind of things, maybe it highlights the fact that your pipeline is not properly designed. If that is not what you want, please provide more details, like a use case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not aware of such a step.

But you could use the `error` step to abort the build with a certain message, if it should succeed. Catch this error in a `try{}catch(){}` block, check for the message and set the build status to success.